# How to get handlers for all open windows and browsers browsers on selenium?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, browser

I am searching for a method that will return the urls and handlers **across all open windows, tabs, and browsers,** not just the one that is currently being run in selenium. My code below only returns the current window that was instantiated by running the current test.

```
String originalWindowHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();
System.out.println("original Window handles are: " + originalWindowHandle);
System.out.println("Title of original Page:" + driver.getTitle());  
java.util.Set<java.lang.String> windowHandles = driver.getWindowHandles();
System.out.println(windowHandles);
int count = windowHandles.size();
//if (count > 1) {
for (String window: windowHandles) {
        String url = driver.getCurrentUrl();
        System.out.println("current url is: " + url);
    }       
//}
```

Comment: What does `System.out.println(windowHandles);` return?

Answer (score 3):

You are getting correct counts. But never switched to newly opened windows. In enhanced for loop you want to switch to each window and then check url

```
String originalWindowHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();
System.out.println("original Window handles are: " + originalWindowHandle);
System.out.println("Title of original Page:" + driver.getTitle());  
java.util.Set<java.lang.String> windowHandles = driver.getWindowHandles();
System.out.println(windowHandles);
int count = windowHandles.size();
//if (count > 1) {
for (String window: windowHandles) {
    if(!window.equals(originalWindowHandle)){
        driver.switchTo().window(window);
        String url = driver.getCurrentUrl();
        System.out.println("current url is: " + url);        
    }  
    //to go back to original    
    driver.switchTo().window(originalWindowHandle); 

}   
//}
```

Comment: thank you Saifur, however that does not resolve the problem I was having with accessing all the open windows and browsers - for example, if there was a window already open on my machine before the test is even run. This method only switches between windows opened by the current test in selenium.
Do you know of any solutions for that?