# Selenium test - Firefox alert disappearing immediately

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, alert

I am writing a Selenium test on Firefox that deals with an alert. The alert appears for a fraction of a second when the test is run, but when done manually the alert persists. Can anyone tell why this is the case?

I tried setting this profile on Firefox, but that did not help either:

```
profile.setPreference("alerts.disableSlidingEffect", true);
```

Can anyone tell how I can make the alert stay on the page?

In the code, I am checking the presence of the alert as this, which apparently is never getting hit since the alert is disappearing too quick:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, Long.parseLong(parameters[0]));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 3 states for `UnexpectedAlertBehaviour`:

1. `ACCEPT` - Accepts the alert
2. `DISMISS` - Closes/Cancels the alert
3. `IGNORE` - Neither accepts nor closes the alert

```
DesiredCapabilities dc = new DesiredCapabilities();
dc.setCapability(CapabilityType.UNEXPECTED_ALERT_BEHAVIOUR, UnexpectedAlertBehaviour.IGNORE);
driver = new FirefoxDriver(dc);
```

Then you can handle the alert by performing the operation that triggers the alert and catching it as an expected exception:

```
try {
    click(myButton);
} catch (UnhandledAlertException f) {
    try {
        Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
        String alertText = alert.getText();
        System.out.println("Alert data: " + alertText);
        alert.accept();
    } catch (NoAlertPresentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The chosen answer worked for me, but it seems that FirefoxDriver(org.openqa.selenium.Capabilities) is deprecated. The working alternative is:

```
FirefoxOptions firefoxOptions = new FirefoxOptions();
firefoxOptions.setCapability(CapabilityType.UNEXPECTED_ALERT_BEHAVIOUR, UnexpectedAlertBehaviour.IGNORE);
driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the 'alerts.disableSlidingEffect' Firefox profile option should be causing the alert to disappear - Instead, try creating your WebDriver instance using the unexpectedalertbehaviour capability set to 'ignore'.

Comment: The alert is expected, and that's what I am testing. I want the alert to appear and stay.

Comment: Please can you share more of your test script and where you expect the alert to appear?