# No modal dialog is currently open exception in selenium

Tags: java, selenium

When I use switch to alert command it shows No modal dialog is currently open exception.

```
driver.switchTo().alert().getText();
```

I also set capability for the browser as ignore.

```
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.UNEXPECTED_ALERT_BEHAVIOUR, UnexpectedAlertBehaviour.IGNORE);
```

Below is the error message i got. Pls help me to come out of it.

```
1500030784208   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:27904
1500030784593   geckodriver::marionette INFO    Starting browser C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe with args ["-marionette"]
[GFX1]: Potential driver version mismatch ignored due to missing DLLs igd10umd32 v= and igd10iumd32.dll v=0.0.0.0
1500030787614   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 54311
Jul 14, 2017 4:43:08 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
3 Registration
FAILED: main
org.openqa.selenium.NoAlertPresentException: No modal dialog is currently open
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-3QEMR32', ip: '192.168.1.23', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{moz:profile=C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\rust_mozprofile.mdPh9bfiW9bk, rotatable=false, timeouts={implicit=0.0, pageLoad=300000.0, script=30000.0}, pageLoadStrategy=normal, platform=ANY, specificationLevel=0.0, moz:accessibilityChecks=false, acceptInsecureCerts=false, browserVersion=54.0.1, platformVersion=10.0, moz:processID=3676.0, browserName=firefox, javascriptEnabled=true, platformName=windows_nt}]
Session ID: e937e2ca-0064-41df-a6b8-9809bf3e2219
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:150)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:115)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:45)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:164)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:637)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:694)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$RemoteTargetLocator.alert(RemoteWebDriver.java:1020)
    at testCases.MandatoryOptionForApprovedByAfterSelectDiscountType.main(MandatoryOptionForApprovedByAfterSelectDiscountType.java:96)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:108)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:661)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:869)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1193)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:126)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:744)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:602)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:380)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:375)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1301)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1226)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1144)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1115)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:230)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:76)
```

Comment: are you sure that the alert is displayed?  You actually see it when you watch the test run?

Comment: Are you sure that the thing that you're expecting is actually a browser alert dialog, or is it some HTML that the application is presenting in the browser itself, made to look like an alert dialog?

Comment: The error `NoAlertPresentException: No modal dialog is currently open` says it all. Definitely it's not an `Alert`. It should be a normal `Dialog Box`. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium test - Firefox alert disappearing immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43925815/selenium-test-firefox-alert-disappearing-immediately)