# Would like to understand why switch_to_alert() is receiving a strikethrough and how to fix

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, alert, webdriverwait

I'm trying to 'accept' a simple modal alert (an onscreen popup with only OK button) but switch_to_alert() in driver.switch_to_alert() is receiving a strikethrough (on pycharm).

I'm using data driven testing script with OpenPyxl. I have written a condition that takes username and password from spreadsheet and adds it to login on webpage. If login is successful the code is work but the 'else' condition (ie. if fails login fails) is giving me issues due to the popup alert and I'm not sure how to close it.

I would like to understand why driver.switch_to_alert() is receiving a strikethough  and how to fix.

I have added the following line at in the 'else' condition "driver.switch_to_alert()" but switch_to_alert() has a strike though.

If i move driver.switch_to_alert() to above the line driver = self.driver then the strikethrough does not occur.

Alternately if i simply write switch_to_alert() in the else condition there is no strikethough but the code fails when the else condition is called. The error message i get is
selenium.common.exceptions.UnexpectedAlertPresentException: Alert Text: None
Message: Dismissed user prompt dialog: User or Password is not valid

I also tried a hard get(back to home page) which also failed.

```
def test_login_valid(self):

    driver = self.driver
    driver.get('http://www.demo.guru99.com/V4/')

    #count how many rows in spreadsheet and add read username and password 
    #and add to www.demo.guru99.com login
    for r in range(2, rows + 1):
        username = spreadsheet.readData(path, "Sheet1", r, 1)
        password = spreadsheet.readData(path, "Sheet1", r, 2)
        login.enter_username(username)
        login.enter_password(password)
        login.click_login()
   #If login is successful then pass test
        if driver.title == "Guru99 Bank Manager HomePage":
            print("test is passed")
            spreadsheet.writeData(path, "Sheet1", r, 3, "test passed")
   #return back to home page - i dont think i should need this line???
            driver.get('http://www.demo.guru99.com/V4/')
        else:
            print("test failed")
            spreadsheet.writeData(path, "Sheet1", r, 3, "test failed")
   #accept the alert popup and close - python is striking though the bold
            driver.switch_to_alert().accept() # error shown on this line
```

I expect when username or password on login is wrong then the "else" condition should be able to select "ok" on the alert notification. This will close the popup and result in test returning back to home page.

Comment: If you hover over the strikethrough text, what does it say?

Comment: That it is deprecated which DebenjanB pointed out. I implemented his suggested solution but now i have another issue (see below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of points:

- [`switch_to_alert()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.switch_to_alert) has been deprecated so you should use [`switch_to().alert`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.switch_to) instead. You can find a relevant discussion in [Python click button on alert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47353964/python-click-button-on-alert/47367059#47367059).
- As per best practices, while switching to an alert, you need to use `WebDriverWait` with `expected_conditions` clause set to [alert_is_present](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.alert_is_present) as follows:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.alert_is_present).accept()
  ```

  You can find a relevant discussion in [Why switching to alert through selenium is not stable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48839355/why-switching-to-alert-through-selenium-is-not-stable/48839525#48839525)

Comment: I changed driver.switch_to_alert().accept() to WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.alert_is_present).accept() and added in                                                
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC                       
but it still fails. I get this error message. selenium.common.exceptions.UnexpectedAlertPresentException: Alert Text: None
Message: Dismissed user prompt dialog: User or Password is not valid.  Is this saying the alert is not an alert?

Comment: I have selenium webdriver version 3.141.0 and python 3.7

Answer (score 0):

Following the advice from `@DebanjanB`, I have changed my code with the following (i only include the code you need for context). 
However, I get the following error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.UnexpectedAlertPresentException: Alert Text: None
Message: Dismissed user prompt dialog: User or Password is not valid
```

One other comment to make when using Pycharm. When you see the word "alert" in in the code it is highlighted in yellow. Pycharm advises Statement seems to have no effect 
Inspection info: This inspection detects statements without any effect. I'm not sure what this means.

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By # **This is greyed out in pycharm. is this** correct?
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

        def test_login_valid(self):

            driver = self.driver
            driver.get('http://www.demo.guru99.com/V4/')
            login = LoginPage(driver)
            for r in range(2, rows + 1):
#inserts username and password from spreadsheet - if username/password does not login the else condition is called and alter is raised. I'm trying to close this popup alert.
                if driver.title == "Guru99 Bank Manager HomePage":
                    print("test is passed")
                    spreadsheet.writeData(path, "Sheet1", r, 3, "test passed")
                    driver.get('http://www.demo.guru99.com/V4/')
                else:
                    print("test failed")
                    spreadsheet.writeData(path, "Sheet1", r, 3, "test failed")
# This line should close the alert but appears to cause error
                    **WebDriverWait(driver, 300).until(EC.alert_is_present).accept**
```

[image of the alert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qrukq.jpg)