# How to Click the "OK" Button within an Alert using Python + Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, alert

I want to click the "OK" button in this pop up dialog

[image]

I tried:

```
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

but it doesn't work

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To *click* on the <kbd>OK</kbd> button within the [alert](/questions/tagged/alert) you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired `alert_is_present()` and you can use the following solution:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.alert_is_present())
driver.switch_to.alert.accept()
```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.alert import Alert
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Python click button on alert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47353964/python-click-button-on-alert/47367059#47367059)
- [How to read the text from the alert box using Python + Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47074558/how-to-read-the-text-from-the-alert-box-using-python-selenium/47075168#47075168)
- [Why switching to alert through selenium is not stable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48839355/why-switching-to-alert-through-selenium-is-not-stable/48839525#48839525)
- [Would like to understand why switch_to_alert() is receiving a strikethrough and how to fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55783153/would-like-to-understand-why-switch-to-alert-is-receiving-a-strikethrough-and/55786168#55786168)

Comment: NameError: name 'WebDriverWait' is not defined

Comment: TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: @CandraHerk Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:62996/devtools/browser/dc61f8e2-7ff6-4713-8e10-7d5d71eec38a
[34368:48752:0518/053839.730:ERROR:browser_switcher_service.cc(238)] XXX Init()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\herk\Programming\intro.py", line 19, in <module>
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.alert_is_present).accept()
  File "C:\Users\herk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 71, in until
    value = method(self._driver)
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: driver.switch_to().alert().accept()
TypeError: 'SwitchTo' object is not callable

Comment: @CandraHerk Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: Maybe a bit late but it works when I did `self.switch_to.alert.accept()`. remove the parenthesis to the `switch_to` and `alert`.

Comment: Is it needed to later change to default driver content using driver.switch_to.default_content()?