# During handling UnexpectedAlertPresentException, NoAlertPresentException occurs in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I was handling UnexpectedAlertPresentException which often occurs, So I made try-except codes to deal with it. I was about to return the content of Unexpected Alert, So My code is

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver2, 10)
try:
    element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, 'wlike_limit')))
except UnexpectedAlertPresentException:
    print("UnexpectedAlertPresentException, ",driver2.switch_to.alert.text)
```

But it also gives me "NoAlertPresentException" while trying to print the text of the unexpected alert.

```
UnexpectedAlertPresentException           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-52-543c0fff5a64> in <module>
     16 try:
---> 17    element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, 'wlike_limit')))
     18 except UnexpectedAlertPresentException:

UnexpectedAlertPresentException: Alert Text: 
Message: unexpected alert open: {Alert text: }
  (Session info: chrome=84.0.4147.125)


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

NoAlertPresentException                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-52-543c0fff5a64> in <module>
     17    element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, 'wlike_limit')))
     18 except UnexpectedAlertPresentException:
---> 19    print("UnexpectedAlertPresentException, ",driver2.switch_to.alert.text)
     20
```

Could anyone help me deal with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message...

```
NoAlertPresentException                   Traceback (most recent call last)
```

...implies that though you attempted to handle an [Alert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47074558/how-to-read-the-text-from-the-alert-box-using-python-selenium/47075168#47075168) but there was no such [alert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61859356/how-to-click-the-ok-button-within-an-alert-using-python-selenium/61859592#61859592).

---

### Analysis

This line of code:

```
except UnexpectedAlertPresentException:
        print("UnexpectedAlertPresentException, ",driver2.switch_to.alert.text)
```

would switch to the alert and retrieve the text when your code block faces *UnexpectedAlertPresentException*. However it seems there was no alert present.

Now in in the `try{}` block:

```
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, 'wlike_limit')))
```

This line won't raise any alert as you are not interacting with the element. Hence, the catching `UnexpectedAlertPresentException` doesn't looks useful to me.

---

### Conclusion

The `try-catch{}` block for handling `UnexpectedAlertPresentException` doesn't looks useful to me. Perhaps your previous code block can provide some hint in which circumstances you wanted to handle *UnexpectedAlertPresentException*.

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Python click button on alert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47353964/python-click-button-on-alert/47367059#47367059)
- [Why switching to alert through selenium is not stable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48839355/why-switching-to-alert-through-selenium-is-not-stable/48839525#48839525)

Answer (score 0):

By my side, when I am attempting to handle `UnexpectedAlertPresentException`. Then I notice that Selenium closes automatically the alert pop-up. Thus in this case ,I just retry my script and it works!

```py
    def some_function:
        try:
            return driver.find_element_by_css_selector(
                "#elementID"
            ).text
        except UnexpectedAlertPresentException:
            # In this case, no need to call driver.switch_to.alert.accept()
            # or driver.switch_to.alert.dismiss()
            time.sleep(5) # very important to wait for selenium to finish the action
            driver.find_element_by_css_selector(
                "#elementID"
            ).text
```